# JavaFX Internationalization with vars in Translated String

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization

I just found out, that JavaFX has a built-in Internationalization feature!
Since I'm starting to rewrite the GUI of my App I'm going to use this handy feature.
The only thing I can't seem to find is how I can add dynamic values into the translated String...
For example:
`chat.message.player_joined=Player %s joined!`
I would like to be able to replace %s with the corresponding player name.
But since the strings are loaded via the properties file and not something like `node.setText(String.format("Player %s joined!", playerName))`.
I have no Idea on how to do that...

I'm using fxml files to format my windows btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MessageFormat` with `messageArguments`.

**CODE**

```
Label l = new Label();

final Locale currentLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", currentLocale);
Object[] messageArguments = {new Integer(5)};

MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat("");
formatter.setLocale(currentLocale);

formatter.applyPattern(bundle.getString("TEST_BUNDLE_TEXT"));
l.setText(formatter.format(messageArguments));
```

**RESOURCE BUNDLE**

```
TEST_BUNDLE_TEXT=Test text with integer {0}.
```

Comment: No it's not necessary in that case.